# VBA API GET that requires request token, authorizing and access tokens

Tags: excel, vba, api, oauth, callback

I am trying to get data from a site that requires you to request tokens, authorize app, get access tokens them make request the data required.

This is the instructions provided:

Using the API

1. Get an API key and API secret (password) from support@example.com.
2. Make an API call and get a request token. 
   GET https://live.example.com/api/v1/oauth/request_token 
   Your request should have the following header: 
   Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="[app-key]", oauth_signature="[app-secret]&"
   The response body will be the following URL-encoded string: 
   oauth_token=[request-token]&oauth_token_secret=[request-token-secret]
   Store those for later use.
3. Have the user authorize your app. Direct the user's browser to 
   https://live.example.com/api/authorize.aspx?oauth_token=[request-token]&oauth_callback=[callback_url].   After completing the authorization process, EXAMPLE will redirect the user to the callback URL with a querystring containing the request token, so that you can match the user and verify that he/she has authorized the app.
4. Make an API call to convert your request token into an access token. 
   GET https://live.example.com/api/v1/oauth/access_token 
   Your request should have the following header: 
   Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="[app-key]", oauth_token="[request-token]", oauth_signature="[app-secret]&[request-token-secret]"
   The response body will be the following URL-encoded string: 
   oauth_token=[access-token>&oauth_token_secret=[access-token-secret>
   Store those for later use and you will be ready to go.
5. Make a test API call to retrieve all the items from the account. GET https://live. example.com/api/v1/items Your request should have the following header: 
   Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="[app-key]", oauth_token="[access-token]", oauth_signature="[app-secret]&[access-token-secret]"

Is it even possible to do all these steps in VBA?

I have been able to use VBA to GET API DATA from other websites that do not require these extra sets of tokens and Authorization. I have tried patching together a lot of different code but I am not getting anywhere.

It would be great to even just get the first piece of the puzzle (authorization) working. I have put one version of code I have tried for this below.

```
Dim strURL As String
strURL = "https://live.EXAMPLE.com/api/v1/oauth/request_token"

Dim hReq As New WinHttpRequest
hReq.Open "GET", strURL, False
hReq.SetRequestHeader "oauth_version", "1.0"
hReq.SetRequestHeader "oauth_signature_method", "PLAINTEXT"
hReq.SetRequestHeader "oauth_consumer_key", "[KEY-I have this]"
hReq.SetRequestHeader "oauth_signature", "[SECRET-I have this]"
hReq.Send

Dim strResp As String
strResp = hReq.ResponseText

MsgBox strResp
```

Comment: My understanding is that protocols like `OAuth 1.0` and `OAuth 2.0` are designed for the scenario where users (of your app) give permission to your app to access the user's stuff or do stuff on behalf of the user. The permission is granted by the user logging in (at which point the server will redirect the user to whatever URL you specified). But it seems like you want to access your own data (so you want to behave as the user and the third-party app and grant permission to yourself -- in terms of `OAuth`).

Comment: Are you willing to share a link/URL to the API documentation? The challenge I see is that you will be prompted for some sort of log-in each time the access token expires. But once you're logged in, you'll need to get the request token. Also, I think you should have `hReq.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "OAuth"`

Comment: Hi chillin, Thanks for replying. We are using a 3rd party inventory system that stores all our data. I am trying to automate some of our report creation. We are currently downloading all the data we require from the site manually into a folder then have a macro that grabs and alters the data into the reports we need.

Comment: I definitely do not want to be prompted each time. It does seem like this is used more so if you are creating steps for a user to log in via an app of some sort to get your data. I am going to go back to our 3rd party inventory host and see if they have any other way for me to do this.

Comment: I can send you all the API documentation that they sent me for this process but there is not much more than what I posted in my original post. Let me know if you would like me to send it to you. Thanks again for replying, your answer has helped me as I think you are correct that they want us to sign in each time.

Comment: yes, I would definitely go back to the provider and specify that you want to access your own data (not somebody else's). If they offer nothing else apart from the authentication flow described in your original post, a couple of options for you: #1 Continue your current approach and when you're prompted to log in (i.e. when the token expires), you automate/emulate the log-in process (either through IE automation, or sending a HTTP POST request to their authentication endpoint, or whatever). This doesn't fix the real problem (which is that

Comment: the credentials/authentication flow isn't technically appropriate for the use case), but it might get you up and running. #2 You forget their API and investigate whether web scraping is possible (i.e. if the links you're clicking to manually download the data can be automated).

Comment: Thanks chillin! It does not look like there is another option available from our provider. I am going to see if I can make the web scrapping work :) Thanks again for your replies and suggestions!